# Printing a string in 16-bit real mode

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, real-mode

I am learning how to work in 16-bit real mode. I am currently trying to print a string. Currently, my `print` function prints a single null character. Does anyone see an issue here?

The `clearscreen` and `movecursor` functions work correctly.

boot_sect.asm

```
[bits 16]
[global _start]

; globals
msg: db "Hello, World!", 0

_start:
  call clearscreen

  push 0x0
  call movecursor

  push msg
  call print

  jmp $

; includes
%include "boot/16bit/console.asm"

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

console.asm

```
clearscreen:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    pusha

    mov ah, 0x07        ; tells BIOS to scroll down window
    mov al, 0x00        ; clear entire window
    mov bh, 0x07        ; white on black
    mov cx, 0x00        ; specifies top left of screen as (0,0)
    mov dh, 0x18        ; 18h = 24 rows of chars
    mov dl, 0x4f        ; 4fh = 79 cols of chars
    int 0x10            ; calls video interrupt

    popa
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret

movecursor:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    pusha

    mov dx, [bp+4]      ; get the argument from the stack. |bp| = 2, |arg| = 2
    mov ah, 0x02        ; set cursor position
    mov bh, 0x00        ; page 0 - doesn't matter, we're not using double-buffering
    int 0x10

    popa
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret

print:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    pusha
    mov si, [bp+4]      ; grab the pointer to the data
    mov bh, 0x00        ; page number, 0 again
    mov bl, 0x00        ; foreground color, irrelevant - in text mode
    mov ah, 0x0E        ; print character to TTY
.char:
    mov al, [si]        ; get the current char from our pointer position
    add si, 1           ; keep incrementing si until we see a null char
    or al, 0
    je .return          ; end if the string is done
    int 0x10            ; print the character if we're not done
    jmp .char           ; keep looping
.return:
    popa
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret
```

I'm expecting an output of "Hello, World!", but I am currently getting this:

[image: output]

Comment: One immediate problem is that you did not set up `ds`.

Comment: Another problem is you have placed `msg` before the code so the processor will execute that data as code before reaching your first instruction which can and likely will cause some undefined behaviour. Place your data after your code (and before the boot signature).

Comment: @MichaelPetch placing `msg` before the boot signature and just after `jmp $` gives me an output of `S\0`

Comment: Sounds like you didn't take Jester's advice to set DS. I'm going to make a recommendation to make this as least painful as possible. Set the origin point at the top to 0x7c00 by adding `org 0x7c00` at the top of boot_sect.asm. You don't specify one so it is likely being set to 0x0000 (or you are using LD to link??). I'd then set _DS_ to zero at the beginning of the code (as the first instructions after the `_start` label). That can be done with `xor ax, ax` `mov ds, ax`

Comment: How are you building your bootloader? With just NASM (outputting a binary image directly) or are you using NASM to generate ELF objects and then using LD or GCC as a linker to make a final binary image?

Comment: If you don't use an org and it does default to 0x0000 then you'd have to move 0x07c0 (NOT 0x7c00) into DS with something like `mov ax, 0x07c0` `mov ds, ax`

Comment: In addition to the above points, I think `mov si, [bp+4]`, should actually be `mov si, [bp + 8]`. You did not take into account the return address in stack.

Comment: @Arjob Mukherjee: This is running in 16-bit real 86 mode, so the `bp` on stack and the `ip` on stack take up 4 bytes together. `(e)bp + 8` would only be right for 32-bit modes.